# Using CoreData in swift from a tableview selection

Tags: swift, core-data, save

I have 2 functions, one which should save the string to a CoreData attribute and another to fetch it. And this was written by copying working code from elsewhere in the project, so I can't figure out why when I print the contents of 'currentSetting' I get nil.

The save function is called from didSelectRowAtIndexPath and it sends in indexPath.row as the parameter and this fetches a String from an array.

```
func getImageSetting() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Settings")
    do {
        let fetcher = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let data = fetcher as? [NSManagedObject]
        if let results = data {
                let settingResult = results[0]
                currentSetting = settingResult.value(forKey: "imageQuality") as? String
                print(currentSetting as Any)
            } else { print ("error") }
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
}

func saveSetting(selection: Int) {
    let coreSelection = choices[selection]
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let itemEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Settings", in: managedContext)!
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: itemEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
    item.setValue(coreSelection, forKey: "imageQuality")
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you say `currentSetting = settingResult.value(forKey: "imageQuality") as? String`, either there is no such key in `settingResult` or, if there is, its value is not a String.

Comment: Does the save function look sound? Because that’s the only way it would be empty or not be a string

Comment: It doesn’t matter how it looks. You asked why you get nil. That’s why. You have the program. You have a wonderful debugger. Debug.

Comment: Your saveSetting function creates a new Settings object each time it runs.  So it’s possible that you have at some point in testing created a Settings object where the imageQuality is nil, and this is the first item returned in the fetchRequest.  Try clearing down (delete the app and reinstall).  Then rework the save function to fetch the existing Settings object, modify it, and save, rather than creating new.  Assuming that’s what you want.

Comment: @pbasdf Thankyou so much. I started changing results[0] to results[4] etc and you were right, I was saving a new object with each row selection. This was solved with a simple predicate prior to the save.